# How do you add a comment to a Microsoft Reporting tablix control expression?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

Is it possible to add a non-visible comment to the expression in a Microsoft Reporting Tablix Control Expression? If is, how do you do it?

For example, I would like to do something like the following within a tablix expression:

```
' Only display the spouse last name if it is different.
=IIF(Fields!SLast.Value <> Fields!PLast.Value, Fields!SLast.Value, "")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put a comment into an expression, but it has to go at the end. Reporting Services expressions are VBA code but they evaluate to one line of VBA code. This means *anything* after the single quote `'` is treated as a comment.

So your example will only evaluate as text and put that text into the textbox. However, this will work:

```
=IIF(Fields!SLast.Value <> Fields!PLast.Value, Fields!SLast.Value, "") ' Only display the spouse last name if it is different.
```

This also works:

```
=IIF(Fields!SLast.Value <> Fields!PLast.Value, Fields!SLast.Value, "") 
' Only display the spouse last name if it is different.
```

But beware of this:

```
=Fields!FirstName.Value + "" 
+ Fields!LastName.Value
' Now add the address
+ Fields!Address.Value
```

In this example the address will never show because the expression gets put into one line and the address is after the comment `'` and so gets commented out. Unfortunately the code highlighter doesn't make this clear and it gets marked up as valid executable code.